# failed to listen and connect winsock2

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2

I have a problem with my Windows socket code, written in C++ using wxDev. The output of the code below is:

```
Starting...
: Compatible...
: Created...
: Binding Done...
: Cannot listen...
: Error connecting...
:::Cleaned:::
```

I do not know why the listen and connect fail.

Code

```
void serverFrm::serverClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    SOCKET sockh, socka;
    WSADATA wsadata;
    sockaddr_in sockAddr;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsadata) == 0) {
        box->AppendText(_(" : Starting...\n"));
    }
    if (LOBYTE(wsadata.wVersion) >= 2) {
        box->AppendText(_(" : Compatible...\n"));
    }

    sockh = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockh != SOCKET_ERROR) {
        box->AppendText(_(" : Created...\n"));
    }
    else {
        box->AppendText(_(" : Error connecting...\n"));
    }

    sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockAddr.sin_port = htons(6788);
    sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    if (bind(sockh, (sockaddr*)(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr)) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
        box->AppendText(_(" : Binding Done...\n"));
    }
    else {
        box->AppendText(_(" : Error binding...\n"));
    }

    if (listen(sockh, SOMAXCONN) != 0) {
        box->AppendText(_(" : Listening...\n"));
    }
    else {
        box->AppendText(_(" : Cannot listen...\n"));
    }

    int siz = sizeof(sockh);
    if (accept(sockh, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&sockAddr), &siz) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
        box->AppendText(_(" : Connected...\n"));
    }
    else {
        box->AppendText(_(" : Error connecting...\n"));
    }

    closesocket(sockh);
    if (WSACleanup() == 0)
        box->AppendText(_(":::Cleaned:::\n"));
}
```

Comment: Indentation is important.

Comment: Did you seriously think that this would be an acceptable form in which to post a question?

Comment: actually i m asking you to help me for proper indentation. so that i would be considered inside help circle.

Comment: You are surely capable of writing indentation yourself. Also to press the "SHIFT" key in order to produce capital letters. You do not need a "help circle" for that: indeed, the "help circle" refuses to do that legwork on your behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(listen(sockh, SOMAXCONN)!=0)
```

[This function returns `0` when it *succeeds*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Your conditional check is backwards.

**Read the documentation** and for the love of Kahless indent your code properly.

Comment: thx now it is listening. now what's next ? Dose it automatically wait for incomming connection by accept function.?

Comment: What's next is you **read the documentation** and find out!